# Generics and Protocols in Swift: Why does my $0 have no expectation member?

Tags: swift

In the code below, when I try to `let expectations = stuffToExpect.map({ $0.expectation })` the compiler says Value of tuple type '(key: _, value: HasExpectations)' has no member 'expectation'.

What is the correct way to use map in with a generic type?

```
    import XCTest
    import Foundation    
    protocol HasExpectations {
        var expectation: XCTestExpectation { get }
    }

    public class A: HasExpectations {
        var expectation: XCTestExpectation

        init(expectation: XCTestExpectation) {
            self.expectation = expectation
        }
    }

    public class B: HasExpectations {
        var expectation: XCTestExpectation

        init(expectation: XCTestExpectation) {
            self.expectation = expectation
        }
    }

    func doit<T>(stuffToExpect: [T: HasExpectations]) {
        let expectations = stuffToExpect.map({ $0.expectation })
    }
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My real problem was my function declaration:

`func doit<T>(stuffToExpect: [T: HasExpectations]) {`

What I really wanted to do was say that T conformed to HasExpectations:

`func doit<T: HasExpectations>(stuffToExpect: [T: HasExpectations]) {`

Answer (score 3):

In your function

```
func doit<T>(stuffToExpect: [T: HasExpectations]) {
    let expectations = stuffToExpect.map({ $0.expectation })
}
```

`stuffToExpect` is of type `[T: HasExpectations]` aka `Dictionary<T: HasExpectations>`. When you map over a dictionary it gives you a tuple of type `(key: T, value: HasExpectations)` back which is why you are seeing that error.

I think you instead wanted to constrain `T` instead and have `stuffToExpect` as an array, in which case the syntax is either of these (pick which you think looks best):

```
func doit<T: HasExpectations>(stuffToExpect: [T]) {
    let expectations = stuffToExpect.map({ $0.expectation })
}

// or

func doit<T>(stuffToExpect: [T]) where T: HasExpectations {
    let expectations = stuffToExpect.map({ $0.expectation })
}
```

Comment: let expectations = stuffToExpect.map { $0.expectation } -> `Value of type 'T' has no member 'expectation'`

Answer (score 1):

You described `T`as generic. That is correct. Now you want to say I am happy to accept any type `T` which conforms to protocol `HasExpectations`. That smeans `<T: HasExpectation>`.

So your function going to look like below

```
func doit<T: HasExpectations>(stuffToExpect: [T]) {
    let expectations = stuffToExpect.map({ $0.expectation })
}
```

You got a compilation error because when you specify `[T: HasExpections]`. The compiler treats as a dictionary, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Call *mapValues* over the expectation,

```
func doit<T>(stuffToExpect: [T: HasExpectations]) {
    let expectations = stuffToExpect.mapValues { $0.expectation }
    // here your expectations is a new dictionary of [Hashable: XCTestExpectation]
    // also note that T is turned to Hashable since you cannot have stuffToExpect key with T, which is not actually Hashable.

    // you can get all test expectations using values
    let testExpectations = Array(expectations.values)
    // here testExpectations is [XCTestExpectation]
}
```

Comment: Although this post was not the answer, it really helped me pinpoint what my problem was (I was passing a dictionary of T : with values conforming to HasExpectations instead of just having the type T conform to HasExpectations).